# PHP database array specific order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a page on my website which displays product categories in a 3x3 tile layout.

Currently I'm getting the distinct product categories out of the database and looping over the returned array to display the 9 tiles.

This is all working fine but the current order of the tiles is alphabetical. The customer has just come back asking to have them in a very specific order and I'm confusing myself over and over about how to achieve this.

Current Order:

```
Agri, Bespoke, Dairy, Farm, Forest, General, Grain, One off, Red Meat
```

Order Wanted:

```
Dairy, Red Meat, Forest, Grain, General, Farm, Bespoke, One off, Agri
```

Can someone point me in the right direction about what would be needed to achieve this?

Comment: Add a column to your DB with the correct order; then order by that column

Comment: I'm using the Silverstripe CMS/Framework so adding a column isn't so straight forward. Also there isn't just a category table so to speak. The product table just has a category column.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the database will return data in the order they were added, unless told otherwise.

You could add `ORDER BY X` to the end of your query to sort them.  If no column exists that could give you that order you could add such a column.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you can't add a new column with the correct sequence, which would really be the preferred method, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM Products
ORDER BY
(Category='Dairy') DESC, (Category='Red Meat') DESC, (Category = 'Forest') DESC
```

... and so on. It's a really weird way of doing it, but it seems to get job done.